# SubGaussian vector constructed from subGaussian components

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, gaussian

We say that a vector $\mathbf{X}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is subGaussian with parameter $s$  if for any unit vector $\mathbf{u}$ and any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ \exp(2 \pi t \langle \mathbf{X},\mathbf{u} \rangle \right] \leq \exp \left( \pi t^2 s^2 \right)$$

Let $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector such that each of its components is subGaussian with the same parameter $s$ (we may have dependent components).

Is the whole vector $\mathbf{X}$ subGaussian? If yes what is its parameter?

Comment: True for fixed $n$, if $n\to\infty$, independence is required. I work with Orlicz norm to define sub-Gaussian, where $\|X\|_{\psi_2}\equiv\inf \{t>0:\mathbb{E}[\exp(X^2/t^2)]\leq2\}$ for scalar $X$ and  $\|X\|_{\psi_2}\equiv \sup_{u\in S^{n-1}}\|\langle X,u\rangle\|_{\psi_2}$ for $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Note $\|X\|_{\psi_2}\asymp s$ in your definition, a rough computation shows $\sqrt{\pi/e}/6\|X\|_{\psi_2}\leq s\leq 12\sqrt{\pi e}\|X\|_{\psi_2}$. Triangle inequality for Orlicz norm gives $\|X\|_{\psi_2}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\|X_{i}\|_{\psi_2}<\infty$, also gives an upper bound for $s$ parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is correct. If $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are mutually independent, $s$-subguassian random variables, then $X=(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is $s$-subgaussian.
$$ E[\exp(2\pi t \langle X, u\rangle)] = E[\exp(2\pi t \sum_{i=1}^n X_i u_i)]=\Pi_{i=1}^nE[\exp(2\pi tX_i u_i)] \le \Pi_{i=1}^n\exp(\pi u_i^2t^2 s^2)$$
$$=\exp(\pi t^2 s^2 \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2) = \exp(\pi t^2 s^2)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But firstly the $X_i$s may not be independent. Secondly the vectors $X_i u_i$ become dependent since the sum of $u_i^2$ is $1$. So you can't apply the expected value of the product to be the product of expected values.

Comment: @C.S., I think scaling random variables doesn't affect independence, it's just coincidence that the sum of squares of scaling factors equals 1.